# mongoose populate doesn't populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a list of users, each user have a list of exercises. I want to aggregate the basic user's info and their exercises to be displayed.

I did the following:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
  type: String,
   required: [true, 'Invalid username'],
   unique: [true, 'This user already exists'],
  },
  exercises: { 
  type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
   ref: 'Exercise' 
  }
})
User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And

```
const exerciseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  description: {type:String, required: true},
  duration: {type:Number, required: true},
  date: {type:Date, required: true},
});

Exercise = mongoose.model('Exercise', exerciseSchema);
```

However, the aggregation part displays only the user's info with an empty array of exercises:

```
 User.
  find().
  populate({
    path: 'exercises',
    model: 'Exercise'
    }).
  exec().
  then(docs => res.json(docs).status(200)).
  catch(err => res.json(err).status(500))
})
```

Gives:

```
[{
"exercises":[],
"_id":"6047b61bc7a4f702f477085b",
"name":"John Smith",
"__v":0}
]
```

Comment: You may be, do not have any exercises in your database if it were not the case we would have been seeing mongo ids. please check and confirm

Comment: @NamitPiriya No, I did some insertions with `user` as the above id.

Comment: can you check in the database if it is the case?

Comment: Already checked, it is in there. Also, If I reverse the order (i.e `Exercise.find()...`) it works fine, each exercise has a user associated with it.

Comment: I couldn't find a documentation example where a model is using a string can you replace your ref to the exercise model variable and then check.

Comment: I used this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following aggregate query to get users and is exercise data.

```
User.aggregate([{
 "$lookup":{
     "localField":"exercises",
     "foreignField":"_id",
     "from":"Exercise",
     "as" :"userExercises"
  }
}])
```

You will get each user with its exercise data.

Comment: The returned `userExercises` array was empty.

Comment: Please do check the name of fields and collections maybe I do have made mistake in their name so compare them once.

Comment: thanks, this works. Just a small typo: should be`foreignField`